# Break python loop when it finds 2 consecutive empty cells

Tags: python, excel, loops, automation, break

I want to count the rows & columns present in an Excel table using a loop, and the loop should stop running on encountering 2 (or more) consecutive empty cells.

```
row_count=0
col_count=0

for a in range(1,temp.max_row+1):
   if temp.cell(row=a,column=2).value!=None:
       row_count= row_count+1
   else:
       break
for b in range(2,temp.max_column+1):
   if temp.cell(row=8,column=b).value!=None:
       col_count=col_count+1
   else:
       break
print(row_count)
print(col_count)
```

However, I cant get a correct result with the method used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check two adjacent cells in each iteration:

```
for a in range(1,temp.max_row+1):
   # Check if the cell is not empty
   if temp.cell(row=a, column=2).value is not None: 
       row_count = row_count + 1

   # Else the cell is empty, check if the next one is also empty
   elif temp.cell(row=a + 1, column=2).value is None: 
       break

for b in range(2,temp.max_column+1):
   if temp.cell(row=8, column=b).value is not None:
       col_count = col_count + 1
   elif temp.cell(row=8, column=b + 1).value is None:
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering my question. I made a few changes and the code below seems to work best for my data.- (The purpose of the code is the measure the dimensions of a table in an excel sheet (the sheet contains multiple such tables). so it has to stop counting if it encounters, say, 2 consecutive empty cells, before it reaches another table.)

```
# A) For 2 consecutive empty cells- 

#for rows: 
for a in range(4, temp.max_row+1):
    if (temp.cell(row=a, column=2).value==None and temp.cell(row=a+1, column=2).value==None): #check if current cell & the following cell is not empty. if empty, it stops counting & exits the loop.
        break
    else:
        row_count=row_count+1


#for columns: 
for b in range(2,temp.max_column+1):
    if (temp.cell(row=20, column=b).value==None and temp.cell(row=20,column=b+1).value==None):
        break
    else:
        col_count = col_count+1
```